# website-scraper getting images with srcset value aswell as src

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

I'm using website-scraper to make some static templates of a node app I'm working on. I cant seem to be able to get images which have srcset values, website-scraper will update the src value, but not the srcset value. Do I need to pass another value in the sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in [github issue](https://github.com/website-scraper/node-website-scraper/issues/405) your `sources` option should contain `{ selector: 'img', attr: 'srcset' }` rule if your html contains tags like

```
<img srcset="/2x.jpg 2x, /1x.jpg 1x" src="/fallback.jpg" >
```

For example:

```
const options = {
  urls: 'http://example.com',
  directory: '/path/to/save/',
  sources: [
    { selector: 'img', attr: 'srcset' }
  ]
};
```